# Stop focus event adding the stopPropagation method issue

Tags: javascript

I want to show only one alert when i focus on this textbar, i'm using the JS stop.Propagation() method to stop the event listener, this don't seems to work, i also want to avoid adding the html attribute "onFocus='' ".
Thank you.

```js
const textbar = document.querySelector('#search');

textbar.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  alert("hi");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Employee Details" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` doesn't *"stop"* the event listener. It prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use a boolean variable to achieve that.

```js
const textbar = document.querySelector('#search');
let focused = false

textbar.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  if(!focused) {
    alert("hi");
    focused=true
  } else {
    focused=false
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Employee Details" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Thank you,it  works but it doesn't re-open the alert when you re-focus after you click out the textbox, should i make the event a click instead ?

Comment: Thank you sir, appreciate it :)